# Giant Pixels on Rendering

Tags: rendering

So I made a small scene, when I click the render button this is what I get:

[image]

Now that's not how its supposed to render I didn't make large pixels.

This is how its supposed to turn out:
 [image]

Plus while rendering I'm getting the transparent image texture in the Camera, I've added a new camera with all the default settings and its still the same.

Kindly let me know if you guys have a solution.

Comment: Can you show us the Camera properties tab?

Answer (score 4):

The percentage entered below the render resolution is a factor that allows you to quickly decrease the output resolution, e.g. to render a smaller preview.

[image: render settings]

You accidentally set this setting to one percent which means the final image has a resolution of 19 by 10 pixels instead of 1920 by 1080.

Comment: Thank you so much that solved it :), funny I didnt notice that :P